# Azure App Configuration LabelFilters in .Net 4.8 Not working Correctly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

I have several App Configuration Keys that are working correctly.  Now one of them I need to have based on Environment so I am trying to use labels.  So I have 2 labels "Production" and "ProductionIntranet".

```
labelFiler=""
```

This brings back all the keys without labels.

According to the documentation this should bring back all null and ProductionIntranet

```
labelFilter="%00,ProductionIntranet"
```

This does not get any of the keys (Not the ones with labels or the null ones)

```
labelFilter="%00"
```

Neither does this.

I am sure this is a simple syntax issue but I am racking my head and I cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.  I am not sure it is the best solution but it works.  I created 2 buulder stores and had the first with no labelFilter (AppSettingsStore) which gave me all the keys without any labels and then I created a second that had ProductionIntranet as a filter(AppSettingsStoreIntraNet).

Then I updated appsettings like this

```
<appSettings configBuilders="Environment,AppSettingsStore,AppSettingsStoreIntraNet">
```

This might be making two calls to App Configuration.  If someone knows how to do this in one ConfigBuilder please let me know.